# Why does Apollo Client download:schema fail with "Error: Cannot find module 'graphql/validation/rules/UniqueTypeNames'"

Tags: graphql, command-line-interface, schema, apollo

I am trying to download a graphql schema with the command

```
apollo client:download-schema --endpoint=https://my-endpoint --header='x-hasura-admin-key: <my key>'
```

I get an error:   `Error: Cannot find module 'graphql/validation/rules/UniqueTypeNames'`

I have the following dependencies and dev-dependencies in package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.4.16",
    "@vue/apollo-composable": "^4.0.0-alpha.15",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "graphql": "^16.0.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.5",
    "vue": "^3.2.20",
    "vue-auth0-plugin": "^2.4.1",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
    "apollo": "^2.33.7",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  }
```

I have just deleted package-lock.json and rerun `npm install` but still get the same error.

Do I need to manually adjust a version for eithe apollo or graphql, and if so, to what?
Or is there some other method to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm- Just set graphql to version 15.7.2 and reinstalled. I have another error, but looks like I have fixed the original error above. I will leave the question open until I verify that this is the case, but if so, there is a possible breaking change on the upgrade to v16.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The CLI is being deprecated for graph downloading](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/rover/migration/). This code works:

`npx rover --output json graph introspect [url here] > schemas/[name here].json`

Answer (score 3):

Set graphql to v15.7.2 in package.json. That works, but also needed to remove node_modules directory, delete the package-lock.json file and rerun npm install to remove some conflicts with multiple graphql library versions

Comment: The real answer is that this feature is being deprecated and they suggest using https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator instead